# Override standard SF1 pages/navigation from global search

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

I have a custom Visualforce page that I'm using to replace the standard account page.  Works great on SF1 via a custom list view page that links to the custom account page.

However, when users use the SF1 global search and they navigate through to the account page from the results they arrive at the standard out of the box page.

Is there a way to override the global search to ensure users always arrive at my custom VF page?

Comment: Please provide us what you have tried so far so that we can help you.